# Incompatibility between package [francais]{babel} and refcheck

Tags: cross-referencing, babel, warnings, refcheck

Below is an example that fails, giving, at compilation:

```
  ! Missing \endcsname inserted.  
  <to be read again>  
                     \penalty   
  l.10 On identifie \ref{eq:xx}
```

With only either the `\usepackage[francais]{babel}` line or the
`\usepackage{refcheck}` line, it compiles smoothly and gives the result
that I expect.

NB: I have used `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` because with only
`\usepackage[francais]{babel}` (and without `\usepackage{refcheck}`), I
get something like:

```
  Package frenchb.ldf Warning: OT1 encoding should not be used for French.  
  (frenchb.ldf)                Add \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} to the preamble  
  (frenchb.ldf)                of your document, on input line 7.
```

but, whether or not I have this `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, I see the
same `\endcsname` error, and, consistently, the same -- incorrect --
output dvi file if compilation is forced with repetitive [enter] keys.

I also tried to change the order of the lines in the preamble.

I could perform the test on two systems:

```
Linux frac 3.18.7-200.fc21.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 11 21:53:17 UTC 2015  
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Linux fric 2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.i686 #1 SMP Wed Jan 28 18:25:26 UTC 2015  
i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Am I doing something wrong?  Could there exist a workaround?

Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{refcheck}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:xx} x=3 \end{equation}
On identifie \ref{eq:xx}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works with `eqxx`... `refcheck` seems to hate the `:` character in the label

Comment: The `:` character is an active character due to `babel`. Does `:` have a special meaning in French language?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's very inconvenient using `:` in label names when using babel-french

Comment: Why don't you use simply `\label{eq-xx}`? Would it be incompatible with `refcheck`?

Comment: @Christian No, the colon (:) has nothing special in French, i.e., it has exactly the same meaning as in English, to the best of my knowledge.  Only the typographic rules related to it are generally assumed different -- basically: space before and after in French instead of no space before, space after in English; but this might depend on editorial policies: it is not uncommon to find the English convention in  French books/newspapers    (Sorry for the late comment, due to a problem with my account.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of problem happens very frequently with the french option of `babel`: it makes some ponctuation characters (; : ? !) active in order to insert proper spacing before them, following the rules of French typography. But then it triggers some bugs with other packages, the most notorious being `tikz-pgf`, and apparently `refcheck` too.

As a workaround, Daniel Flipo, maintainer of the `frenchb` module for `babel`, proposes to enclose the command `\NoAutoSpacing` into TeX groups containing the problematic parts, as such:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel} % `french` now preferable to `francais` or `frenchb`, D. Flipo tells us
\usepackage{refcheck}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \NoAutoSpacing
    \label{eq:xx} x=3 
\end{equation}
On identifie {\NoAutoSpacing\ref{eq:xx}}.

\end{document}
```

Of course, this is a general solution and in that precise case it is better to avoid the `:` in label names, as egreg and Bernard suggest! :-)

See the [`frenchb` module documentation](http://daniel.flipo.free.fr/frenchb/frenchb-doc.pdf) for more information.